# TS2345 and TS2339 errors are thrown for simple code in Angular

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am trying to learn to use D3 with angular. As a beginner I am trying to implement a simple project written by William Liu a few years ago (http://bl.ocks.org/WilliamQLiu/76ae20060e19bf42d774)
I could replicate most of the code but get compilation errors as below :

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'BaseType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ContainerElement'.
>     Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ContainerElement'.
>       Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'SVGGElement'.
>         Property 'farthestViewportElement' is missing in type 'Element'.
>
> error TS2339: Property 'dataset' does not exist on type 'BaseType'.
>     Property 'dataset' does not exist on type 'Element'.
>
> error TS2339: Property 'dataset' does not exist on type 'BaseType'.
>     Property 'dataset' does not exist on type 'Element'.

I have created a component called dragex. The code is as below

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';


@Component({
  selector: 'dragex',
  templateUrl: './dragex.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dragex.component.css']
})
export class DragexComponent implements OnInit {
 private dataset = [
    { x: 100, y: 110 },
    { x: 83, y: 43 },
    { x: 92, y: 28 },
    { x: 49, y: 74 },
    { x: 51, y: 10 },
    { x: 25, y: 98 },
    { x: 77, y: 30 },
    { x: 20, y: 83 },
    { x: 11, y: 63 },
    { x:  4, y: 55 },
    { x:  0, y:  0 },
    { x: 85, y: 100 },
    { x: 60, y: 40 },
    { x: 70, y: 80 },
    { x: 10, y: 20 },
    { x: 40, y: 50 },
    { x: 25, y: 31 }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.drawchart();
  }

  private drawchart() {
    const margin = {
      top: 40,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 40
    },
    width = 960, // window.innerWidth,
    height = 500, // window.innerHeight,
    radius = 6;

  let svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .attr('width', width )
      .attr('height', height);

  let xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(this.dataset, function(d) { return d.x + 10; })])
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);

    let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(this.dataset, function(d) { return d.y + 10; })])
    .range([margin.top, width - margin.bottom]);

    let xAxis = d3.axisTop(xScale);
    let yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

    let circleAttrs = {
      cx: function(d) { return xScale(d.x); },
      cy: function(d) { return yScale(d.y); },
      r: radius
    } ;

    svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'axis')
      .attr( 'transform', 'translate(' + [margin.left, 0] + ')')
      .call(yAxis);

    svg.selectAll('circle')
      .data(this.dataset)
      .enter().append('circle')
      .attr('cx', circleAttrs.cx)
      .attr('cy', circleAttrs.cy)
      .attr('r', circleAttrs.r)
      .on('mouseover', handleMouseOver)
      .on('mouseout', handleMouseOut);

    svg.on('click', function() { 
      let coords = d3.mouse(this);

      let newData = {
        x: Math.round(xScale.invert(coords[0])),
        y: Math.round(yScale.invert(coords[1]))
      };


      this.dataset.push(newData);


      svg.selectAll('circle')
      .data(this.dataset)
      .enter().append('circle')
      .attr('cx', circleAttrs.cx)
      .attr('cy', circleAttrs.cy)
      .attr('r', circleAttrs.r)
      .on('mouseover', handleMouseOver)
      .on('mouseout', handleMouseOut);

    });




    function handleMouseOver(d, i) {
      d3.select(this)
        .attr('fill', 'green')
        .attr('r', radius * 2 );

      svg.append('text')
        .attr('id', 't' + d.x + '-' + d.y + '-' + i)
        .attr('x', function() { return xScale(d.x) - 30 ; })
        .attr('y', function() { return yScale(d.y) - 15 ; })
        .text(d.x + ',' + d.y );

    }

    function handleMouseOut(d, i) {
      d3.select(this)
        .attr('fill', 'black')
        .attr( 'r', radius);

      d3.select('id').remove();
    }
  }
}
```

The errors are thrown on 
`let coords = d3.mouse(this);`
`this.dataset.push(newData);`
`.data(this.dataset)`

The plunker for the same is available at 
https://plnkr.co/edit/pM5ZsVw7EOm4bMI94JKj?p=info

On hovering over `this` in the above lines it shows `d3.BaseType` whereas ideally it should show `this: this`

I have had a look at other articles but none of them is pointing at the same solution.

Help!

===========================================================================

I shifted out the functions in that code into a new function (as below) and the errors go away. 
Just have a DOM error now that shows `this.dataset.push` is not a function.

```
function onClickIn(d, i) {
  let coords = d3.mouse(this);
  console.log('here in onclick function');

  let newData = {
    x: Math.round(xScale.invert(coords[0])),
    y: Math.round(yScale.invert(coords[1]))
  };

  console.log('new point- x:'+ newData.x + ',' + newData.y);
  this.dataset.push(newData);

  svg.select('circle')
    .data(this.dataset)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', circleAttrs.cx)
    .attr('cy', circleAttrs.cy)
    .attr('r', circleAttrs.r)
    .on('mouseover', handleMouseOver)
    .on('mouseout', handleMouseOut);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
let coords = d3.mouse(this);
```

For

```
let aux:any = this
let coords = d3.mouse(aux);
```

This way you fool the Typescript Compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Use [type assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html)

```
const coords = d3.mouse(this as SVGGElement);
```